# SQL object - How to use it properly

Tags: php, sql, class, object, mysqli

I've made this class to handle all of my sql-queries. But I'm unsure of how to use it properly.

The class looks something like this (this is a VERY simple version of it):

```
class sql {
    private $conn;
    private $data;

    function __construct() {
        //makes connection to DB and sets $conn and $data
    }
    public function select($variables, $table, $criterias) {
        //returns an array with all the info from DB
    }
    function __destruct() {
        //closes the sql-connection
    }
}
```

The question now is: Is this going to overload the DB, if I use it multiple times on every page-load? (refered to as Example #1)

```
$dbInfo = (new sql)->select($var,$tab,$cri);
$moreInfo = (new sql)->select($var2,$tab2,$cri2);
$evenMoreInfo = (new sql)->select($var3,$tab3,$cri3);
```

Would it be beneficial to make my `sql` class's methods static?

Or should I not create a new instance of a `sql` object every time I want to make a query (like the example below - refered to as Example #2)?

```
$sql = new sql();
$dbInfo = $sql->select($var,$tab,$cri);
$moreInfo = $sql->select($var2,$tab2,$cri2);
$evenMoreInfo = $sql->select($var3,$tab3,$cri3);
```

How and when is Example #1 the better choice over Example #2, and vice versa?

If I assume that Example #1 is going to take the most resources from the DB, when would you pick Example #1 over Example #2?

Comment: At leas with second example you will connect to database *once*

Comment: Also, as though this question being simplified, I still don't understand how it is going to handle JOINS, sub-selects, WHERE conditions like `WHERE YEAR(date) BETWEEN '2010' AND '2013' OR cat IN (1,2,3)`, GROUP BY an so on...

Answer (score 0):

Your example 2 is more common to see, however the SQL object is usually a static/singleton. So it connects to the database once per server request.

Your base SQL object should handle connecting to a database and then handle basic input/output, such as executing a string of SQL and returning the results.

You can then add new objects on top of that for each object/table than then interfaces with this SQL singleton. These classes will handle constructing their custom SQL based on their table, joins, field names/types, etc.

E.g:

A very basic 'table' object looks like this

```
class SomeTableObject
{
    m_TableName = 'SomeTable'; // Table to get Data from

    function GetSelectSQL()
    {
       return "SELECT * FROM ".$this->m_TableName;
    }

    function Select($where)
    {
        $sql = $this->GetSelectSQL().$where;
        return SqlSingleton::Execute($sql);
    }

    function GetByID($id)
    {
       $where = " WHERE FieldNameForID=$id";
       return $this->Select($where);
    }
}
```

These objects work better if they extend a base class that has those basic GetSelectSQL, TableName, Select, etc functions. The GetByIDs (and other gets, updates, inserts) will vary from table to table.

Comment: Are you sure you want to inject $id directly into query?

Comment: It's just a basic example off what he's given. I'd personally use PDO and prepared statements but it would have been more work for me.